# Google Play app signng key versus Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Forgive me if this isn't the appropriate venue for this question.  What are the pros/cons, if any of having Google Play manage your keys instead of or in addition to Visual Studio?

[image]

Comment: TL;DR; If you lose your local Java Keystore (or forget the password) that you sign your apks with, you can not update them on Play. Using Google to manage your signing key, you can always re-create a new upload key. Also if Xamarin.Android ever adds support for native Android App Bundles, you have to have Google sign your apk as they are the ones that are actually bundling and signing it for download via Play. Cons: Do you trust Google to "not do evil" to your app   .... Click the Learn More link in the Play console for more details...

Comment: Cool thanks for the help.  I would mark this as an answer